# Drush issue duplicating includes/ directory

Tags: 7, drush

Using drush either globally or with a composer installed version, I get this double includes showing up in my fatal error (/includes/includes/):

> include_once(/srv/www/htdocs/sites/drupal/includes/includes/entity.inc): failed to open stream: No such file or directory bootstrap.inc:3492                          [warning]
> include_once(): Failed opening '/srv/www/htdocs/sites/drupal/includes/includes/entity.inc' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/php7.3/lib') bootstrap.inc:3492        [warning]
> Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.                                                                                                    [error]
> Error: Class 'DrupalDefaultEntityController' not found in include_once() (line 300 of /srv/www/htdocs/sites/drupal/modules/user/user.module).

Anyone ever see this before or have any ideas on why this is happening?

The site is located in the /drupal directory.

Comment: Which version of Drush? Drupal 7 needs Drush 8.

Comment: Good comment. Using drush 8.4.8

Answer (score 3):

I think you might want to use [Registry Rebuild](https://www.drupal.org/project/registry_rebuild) to fix this, as it's most likely a problem with a borked [registry](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/creating-custom-modules/drupal-7s-code-registry).